Connectedness in quotient topology implies connectedness in original space
I am reading Bradley, Bryson, Terilla book in topology from a categorical perspective [1].
Context:
The theorem 2.2 is as follows
Let $X$ be a space, $Y$ be a set, and $f: X \to Y$ be a surjective map in the category Set. If $Y$ in connected in the quotient topology and each fiber $f^{-1}y$ is connected then $X$ is connected.
Previously, quotient topology and connectedness were defined as follows
Let $X$ be a space, $Y$ be a set, and $f: X \to Y$ be a surjective map in the category Set. The quotient topology $\mathcal{T}_Y$ on $Y$ is characterized by universal property as follows: given any morphism $g: (X, \mathcal{T}_X) \to (Z, \mathcal{T}_Z)$ in Top, there is a lift $\bar{g}: (Y, \mathcal{T}_Y) \to (Z, \mathcal{T}_Z)$ such that $g = \bar{g}f$
A space $X$ is connected if the only continuous map $X \to \{0, 1\}$ is constant where $\{ 0, 1\}$ is equipped with the discrete topology.
My Proof:
Let $g: X \to \{ 0, 1\}$ be a continuous map, we will prove that $g$ is constant.
By the universal property of quotient space, $g$ factors through $f$ via $\bar{g}: (Y, \mathcal{T}_Y) \to {0,1}$ where $\mathcal{T}_Y$ denotes the quotient topology. That is, $g = \bar{g} f$. Because $Y$ is connected, by the definition of connectedness, $\bar{g}$ is constant. $\bar{g}$ being constant implies $g$ being constant.
Question:
I am not sure what went wrong with my proof as it doesn't requires fibers of $f$ being connected. As a counterexample, if $X$ is the two-point space with discrete topology, $Y$ is one-point space, $f$ is the only map $X \to Y$, then $X$ is clearly disconnected.
[1] https://topology.mitpress.mit.edu/

I think you need some extra conditions on $g$ to get the lift $\bar{g}$. Your universal property doesn't match the one in Theorem 1.2

@S.C. thank you

The correct universal property for the quotient space is

Given any continuous function $g : (X, \mathcal{T}_X) \to (Z, \mathcal{T}_Z)$ in Top, if $g$ factors through $f : X \to Y$ in Set as $g = \bar{g}f$, then $\bar{g}$ is continuous as a function $(Y, \mathcal{T}_Y) \to (Z, \mathcal{T}_Z)$.

Phrased another way, a function $\bar{g} : Y \to Z$ is continuous if and only if $g := \bar{g}f$ is continuous.
This $\bar{g}$ exists when $g$ is constant on each fiber of $f$. The intuition here is that $f$ maps each fiber to a single point, and for $\bar{g}$ to be defined on that point, it should match the value of $g$ on the fiber. This implies that $g$ can only take one value on that fiber.

So to complete the proof, you need to show that your $g : X \to \{0, 1\}$ is constant on each fiber of $f$. This is where you'll use the connectedness of the fibers.

thank you for the answer. in summary, the existence of the continuous map $\bar{g}$ comes after the existence of the set map.
